# Extract text into new file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with the following format

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
.
.
);

CREATE TABLE `b` (
.
.
);
```

and so on and so on...

I want to extract individual tables and am trying with sed but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sed -n '/^CREATE\sTABLE\s`a`/,/^;$/p' file
```

This is unfortunately not providing the intended behavior. It is producing the entirety of the file instead of just the code block.

It should only grab one code block.

Found issue (dumb typo):

```
sed -n '/^CREATE\sTABLE\s`a`/,/;$/p' file
```

Comment: What is the rule? Are there no blank lines within a block, or no parentheses, or no semicolons, or what?

Comment: Semicolon followed by a newline character between the tables are what compromises a code block.

Comment: there are no `^;$` lines in the test input. There are `^);$` lines.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. ^;$ just means search until the ;

Comment: I just noticed I had an extra ^ that was causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= '$3=="`a`"' file
CREATE TABLE `a` (
.
.
);

$ awk -v RS= '$3=="`b`"' file
CREATE TABLE `b` (
.
.
);
```

If that's not what you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and the associated expected output.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` and suppressing the last line by `head -n -1`

```
# sed -ne '/CREATE TABLE `b`/,/CREATE TABLE/p' tmp7|head -n -1
CREATE TABLE `b` (
.
.
);
```